# Analyse Code - factorial function

Tags: c, factorial

I'm analysing a code and I'm not sure why it is not working (while it compiles I become a windows msg that the program doesn't work anymore and it needs to be closed).

Code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
int factorial(int input)
{
  if (input > 0)
  {
    return input *factorial(input--);
  }
return 1;
}

int main()
{
printf("%d",factorial(23));
return 0;
}
```

So at first i thought there will be an overflow, so I tried numbers like 2 and 3, still not working. 
So I thought maybe it will work if I add

```
int x = 23;
```

and exchange the 23 with '&x' in the print function. Didn't work either.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression

```
return input *factorial(input--);
```

does a post increment of `input`. The value passed to `factorial` is still `input`.

Not only that, you are also in undefined behavior territory since, `input` is also used in the expression.

Given `input = 3`,

```
input *factorial(input--);
```

would easily be:

```
2 *factorial(3);
```

or

```
3 *factorial(3);
```

You should use:

```
return input *factorial(input-1);
```

Comment: 15 sec comment pause, and now I hit that button 4 times too early so countdown reset xD 
Thank you for your answer, now it works just fine :)

Answer (score 3):

Operator `input--` first passes current value, then decreases the variable, and
you're getting an infinite loop.

Use `input * factorial(input - 1)`.

You could use `input * factorial(--input)`. In this case the `input` will be first decremented, then used, so you break an infinite recursion.

But this is a bad idea. The fact is operators (i.e. '*' in this case) can calculate operands in any order. F.e. compiler can calculate the second operand, i.e. `factorial(--input)`, and then the value of `input` will be decremented.

After multiplying your result will be `newInput * factorial(newInput)` while you want to get `oldInput * factorial(newInput)`.

Most worrying, the result depends on a version of a compiler, or parameters of a command line, so you can't predict it absolutely.

Comment: If you use `--input`, you are in undefined behavior territory since `input` is also used in the expression.

Comment: @RSahu, you right, it's better use `input - 1`. I'd corrected my answer.

Comment: UB is *worse* than unspecified ordering. And this is the former. This coment captures the essence: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28034675/analyse-code-factorial-function/28034719?noredirect=1#comment44455408_28034813